# mongoose connection authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, mongoose, pem

I am able to connect to MongoDB from Nodejs (mongoose) with simple userid, password in the URI.

Now if I have a private key (.pem file), do you know how to use ssl_certificate and/or ca_certificate with mongoose driver to connect to Mongo?

I have not found any mongoose specific module to use a .pem file to connect to mongo.

Comment: Check [this](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/server.html) out.

Comment: Thanks for your response. the one you provided is the mongodb native driver. is there anything for mongoose ?

Comment: Since mongoose uses node-mongodb-native internally, there must be [a way](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) to pass it required parameters.